# Using VBA to access an Access Database in Excel to transfer bulk data from a spreadsheet - error in query

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the from clause in the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO [tblFYPNameStudents] ([FypID], [Title], [StudentName]) SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Data Source='C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\testwb.xlsm'].Sheet1$A5:C26
```

It results in 'Error 80040e14, syntax error in From Clause'

The code is as follows : (I'm new to VBA and all this but i couldn't figure out what is wrong. I think it has to do with the bit in the from clause where I specify excel and the data source)

```
Sub AccImport(tblName As String, _
    hasf As Boolean, _
    tblrange As String)
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
sDB_Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sDB_Path
strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
dsh = tblrange
cn.Open scn
ssql = "INSERT INTO " & tblName
MsgBox ssql
ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Data Source='" & dbWb & "']." & dsh
MsgBox ssql
cn.Execute ssql
End Sub
```

Comment: You should say that what are the imputed parameters when you call 'AccImport' method. If so, we can help more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right - it should read:

```
ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=" & dbWb & "].[" & dsh & "]"
```

Comment: That fixes the select from issue and I checked what recordset I get using Print.Debug but now I get an error with the insert into statement. 
My excel sheet has values like '1,Project Name with spaces, student name with spaces' and so on. The error I get is that 1 is not a valid field name. 
If i try insert into ... values (1,"foo bar", "jon doe") it works just fine.... 
what am i missing ?

Comment: If you don't actually have a header row in the worksheet, use `HDR=NO`